Document is not defined while adding component in next js from outside library
I am creating next js app and I would like to use components from outside UI library. But when I import those components i got document is not defined. Error appears when I am adding Link component
My code:
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from '@example/example-UI-library-react';

interface CardProps {
    image: string;
    country: string;
}

const Card: React.FC<CardProps> = ({
   image,
   country
}:CardProps): JSX.Element => (
<a className="card" target="_blank">
  <div className="card__picture">
    <img src={image}></img>
  </div>
  <div className="card__content">
    <h3 className="card__content-country">{country}</h3>
    <Link></Link>
  </div>
</a>
);

export default Card;

And as I have written i got error:
I am aware that it is due fact that nextjs is SSR and react is on client side but have no idea how to solve it. Any ideas? Use other frameworks like express js?

I don't see any document in your code

Have you tried adding use client directive on top of page to mark your component as client?

Because document is declared in external library not in my code

It's challenging to pinpoint the exact reason for this error without more context. However, here are a couple of suggestions to troubleshoot the issue:

Ensure you've imported the necessary dependencies correctly. Consider adding "use client" at the top of the component file if it's relevant to your setup.

If you're importing the Link component from an external UI library (e.g., @example/example-UI-library-react), try dynamically importing it instead. You can achieve this by using the import() function.


import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const DynamicLink = dynamic(() => import('@example/example-UI-library-react').then(module => module.Link));


Then use DynamicLink in your component

